# Audioquest Dragonfly black green light

Tags: 20.04, sound, usb, soundcard, external-soundcard

I have Audioquest Dragonfly Black, v1.5

It says on their website, when light is blue, it's registered on 48 khz
when light is green it's 44.1 khz

When I plug it on laptop under windows, it's blue light, but when I plug it in the same laptop under Ubuntu 20.04 it's green light.

Any ideas how to get it to perform at 48k in Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get blue light, after following tutorial **"Enable High Quality Audio on Linux"** from 2018 published on [medium.com](https://medium.com/@gamunu/enable-high-quality-audio-on-linux-6f16f3fe7e1f)

I've modified original config code to fit ubuntu 20.04:

```
default-sample-format = float32le
default-sample-rate = 48000
alternate-sample-rate = 44100
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 2
default-fragment-size-msec = 125
resample-method = soxr-vhq
remixing-produce-lfe = no
remixing-consume-lfe = no
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 9
rlimit-rtprio = 9
daemonize = no
```

into: **/etc/pulse/daemon.conf**

Alsa config on 20.04 is moved to: **/usr/share/alsa/pulse-alsa.conf**

You can copy it to pulse-alsa.conf.old and edit original file with:

with following content:

```
# Use PulseAudio plugin hw
pcm.!default {
   type plug
   slave.pcm hw
}
```

But I have figured out that original alasa config file works better for me!

To restart alsa and pulse, following command works on ubuntu 20

```
sudo killall pulseaudio && sudo alsa force-reload && sleep 2 && sudo killall pulseaudio && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Difference is very much audible, very much!